# Can Canonical Landscape be used with Ubuntu-derived distros?

Tags: openstack, cloud, landscape, openstack-autopilot

Can Canonical's Landscape systems management tool be used to manage (in whole or in part) Ubuntu-derived distros? In particular, Linux Mint? My hope is that there's enough similarities to allow Landscape to work.

Thanks for the help!

**FYI** This post is asking about the capabilities of Canonical's Landscape service. I feel this forum is the appropriate place to ask these questions and, judging by the number of Landscape questions already listed, most everyone else does too. It is misguided to simply seize upon the use of the name of another distro and throw the whole post out the window. Oh! Wait! He mentioned Windows now... better ban for sure now.

Comment: If you want to try it may be easier to start with a Ubuntu base system, then add the Linux Mint repos and install/update (YMMV). Sorry about the off-topic but this site is for [Ubuntu and 'official' flavours](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), so for Linux Mint is pretty always put as off-topic...

Comment: I've had some thoughtful answers from the more helpful members of this community so I'll count this as a gain, but I swear, in this world I've never encountered anything more small-minded than Forum Policers with a search profile. If I were asking questions requiring detailed knowledge of another 'flavour' then I'd get it, but I'm not--I'm asking for knowledge of a tool based on Ubuntu that will be used to mainly manage Ubuntu servers and that helps fund the makers of Ubuntu. Ok, rant done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to find `landscape-client` for mint, however, do you really want to?  The system is able to find and detect packages that are needed among other tasks.  But without using official ubuntu repos, would you want Ubuntu telling you what you should install?

Comment: Well, no. *I* don't. But the company I work for is required to be PCI compliant and that means certain things like enabled screen locking, firewall configuration, and installed anti-virus need to be verifiable.

The Ops folks would use Landscape to, ideally, manage these settings. Worst case Landscape would be used to periodically verify that the requirements are met.

Comment: I'll go along with that...  You'll have to test it and see if it will work in your environment.  I don't work within the API of landscape, I use the built in functionality for Ubuntu, so I can't speak to checking the types of things you're looking for, but I believe they'll have to be scripted and have limited interaction with landscape.  It wouldn't be much of a step to create a simple interface that your clients report to, if you're doing all of that work.  Or you could script and report to Geckoboard or something similar, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr**: it might work, but you're completely on your own, despite having to pay for a seat.

Landscape-client does not explicitly check that it is running on Ubuntu, however it assumes it does. In other words, absolutely no effort is made by Canonical to test or otherwise support other distributions, but it might work (I personally see no technical reason why it wouldn't, but never tried).

As far as packages go, it should be no problem as Landscape already handles i.e. PPA packages or private repositories quite well.

Needless to say, running landscape client on a non-Ubuntu machines is not recommended and not supported for the following reasons:

- Absolutely no testing is done on non-Ubuntu distributions. A *lot* of testing goes into making sure it works perfectly on Ubuntu, however.
- Features are developed assuming Ubuntu (dependencies are expected to be Ubuntu's for example)
- You'll still need to use up a Landscape seat (which costs money)
- Bugs open against other distributions are likely to be "won't fixe'd".

Comment: Thanks Tribaal.

I figured that Ubuntu would be the favourite child and all others would be second rate. I plan on using the On-Premises version so at least it won't cost me anything if it's an absolute failure.